# How to schedule a job every 10 mins using JIL script

Tags: autosys

How can I set a job in autosys which will run evening from 4pm to 5pm every 10 minutes?

Please help me how I can specify then start time parameter. I am new to this JIL script.

Also where can I get the complete details about scheduling a job using JIL script?

Answer (score 5):

You can give the attribute start_mins for every 10 mins with the run_window. You can schedule jobs for every minute but you do not have it in seconds.

```
date_conditions: 1

days_of_week: all

start_mins: 00,10,20,30,40,50

run_window: "16:00-17:00"

timezone: india
```

Comment: There is no `start_mis` property. You probably meant `start_mins`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* ----------------- template ----------------- */

insert_job: template job_type: c 
box_name: box1
command: <xxx>
machine: <hostname>
owner: <username>
permission: gx,ge
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: all
start_mins: 0,30
run_window: "16:00-17:00
```

please refer to the cheatsheet for further details
http://supportconnectw.ca.com/public/autosys/infodocs/autosys_cheatsheet.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `start_mins: "00,10,20,30,40,50"`